# Web site that collects and discusses Cocoa Touch design patterns?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, design-patterns

Does anyone know of one? If it doesn't exist, anyone interested in collaborating to create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:
Also see: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/

Best site so far is here, and http://www.iphoneexamples.com/

Others are iosdevelopertips.com, iphonedevsdk.com, iphone.zcentric.com, and of course the official Apple Dev forums.

I've come across many (mostly barcamp) communities who begin such efforts but haven't had the time to follow through. I would agree such a site would be useful because there are many challenges cocoa touch presents which aren't present with OS X (memory, performance, no background processes, etc.).

I can only come to the conclusion that everyone is under their employer/client NDAs and/or everyone is too busy to create such a site!

Comment: I'm going to award you the right answer because you pointed me at a couple of sites I'd not seen before. I think you're right - everyone is too busy. Maybe I'll find time to start one myself. Maybe...

Comment: I cannot find any design patterns at these sites. They do contain some framework and stuff, but that is NOT design patterns.

Answer (score 3):

The [delegate pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) is a design pattern that is pretty central to making the most of a number of `UIKit` classes. Apple's developer documentation pages ([example](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)) would be good web resources that collect information about related methods.

**EDIT**: [Here's a page](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/06/five-approaches-to-listening-observing.html) on Cocoa implementations of the observer pattern. [Here's a book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321535022) on Cocoa implementations of design patterns. With respect to iPhone development, <strike>KVO</strike> Cocoa bindings haven't yet been implemented.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a site that collected many patterns though.

Comment: What other patterns were you interested in? Patterns seem to be platform agnostic, for the most part.

Comment: This is wrong; Key Value Observing is fully supported in the iPhone SDK. Cocoa bindings aren't implemented, but the underlying KVO mechanism is fully in place.